# Finding conditional independence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am having a bit of an issue with proving conditional independence for two events. Any attempts to tackle the following problem result in quote a few branched cases and overall way too much effort for something looking like this. What am I missing?

~

Let $X, Y \in U(0,1)$ be independent random variables.

For which value of the parameter $c$ the events {$|X-Y| \geq c $} and {$X+Y \leq 3c$} are independent?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean "which values" in the plural? Clearly they're independent for all $c\le0$ and $c\ge1$.

Comment: @joriki The original formulation is in singular. How did you find the result you mentioned?

Comment: In those cases, these events have probability $0$ or $1$, and such events are always mutually independent.

Comment: (I'm not saying those are the only values – I suspect the problem is asking you to find a more interesting value in $(0,1)$ where they're also independent – I'm just saying there are at least those, and thus plural, values.)